# the example for annotation from xtend 2.4.0 document doesn't work

Tags: xtend

the below code is from xtend's official site.

```
@TypeAnnotation("some value")
  class MyClass {
    @FieldAnnotation(children = #[ @MyAnno(true), @MyAnno(false) ])
    String myField5.  

    @MethodAnnotation(children = #[ @MyAnno(true), @MyAnno ])
    def String myMethod(@ParameterAnnotation String param) {
      //...
    }
}
```

but the line "@MethodAnnotation(children = #[ @MyAnno(true), @MyAnno ])" doesn't work. Eclipse report :

no viable alternative at input ']' 
mismatche input '@' expecting ']'

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, you're stumbling across a bug. Could you please file a ticket at [eclipse](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=Xtend). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a bug in 2.4.0. The issue can be found in [Bugzilla](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=404273).